# Is it possible to use rb_cIPSocket in ruby C extension

Tags: ruby, ruby-c-extension

I am learning how to write Ruby C extensions and I'm past the simplest examples. I was trying to achieve something with sockets so I attempted to create an extension which would define a class under `rb_cIPSocket`.

At the top of my C file I have:

```
#include "rubysocket.h"
```

And I am receiving:

```
...s.c:3:31: error: rubysocket.h: No such file or directory
```

Which is most probably the case. However, I tried all possible paths:

```
#include "rubysocket.h"
#include "socket/rubysocket.h"
#include "ext/socket/rubysocket.h"
#include <rubysocket.h>
#include <socket/rubysocket.h>
#include <ext/socket/rubysocket.h>
```

And this is my `extconf.rb`:

```
require 'mkmf'
dir_config("my_ext")
have_library("c", "main")
create_makefile("my_ext")
```

And so on. What am I actually missing here? Why can't I include that header file?
I am using OSX with RVM and Ruby 1.9.3-p448.
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

where does rubysocket.h live? If it's in the heart of ruby's source code then odds are it is "private" for ruby's use, but you can look it up like...

> VALUE ipSocketClass = rb_const_get("IPSocket");

or the like.
GL!

Comment: Thank you for the pointer. This did the trick for me: `ipSocketClass = rb_const_get(rb_cObject, rb_intern("IPSocket"));`

Comment: Here's more advanced resource: http://clalance.blogspot.be/2011/01/writing-ruby-extensions-in-c-part-3.html

Comment: And here's the best resource, so it seems: http://media.pragprog.com/titles/ruby3/ext_ruby.pdf